# MYSQL : get unique substrings from string

Tags: mysql

example field in mysql table with only one row:

**james is a good boy james he is good and is active**

```
  SELECT FUNCTION(field) 
  FROM table
```

should return only the unique words in the field:

**james is a good boy he and active**

I know how to do this using PHP.

I wish to do this **using MYSQL**.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: people are going to harass you about whether you've tried anything... so, what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried some string functions like SUBSTRING_INDEX(), but I didn't get the desired result. I am using the query in sphinx search. So, I wish to use only mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has little support for regular expressions, so you the resulting solution could be a little complicated:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(word ORDER BY min_n SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    MIN(numbers.n) min_n,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tableName.st, ' ', numbers.n), ' ', -1) word
  FROM
    numbers INNER JOIN tableName
    ON LENGTH(st)>=LENGTH(REPLACE(st, ' ', ''))+numbers.n-1
  GROUP BY
    id, word
  ) s
GROUP BY
  id
```

(You need to have a numbers table). Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2768c/1).

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot for the quick reply and for the example in sqlfiddle.